# How does one minify a javascript partial within a rails erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The application is not using the standard asset pipeline due to having some of the javascript being rendered dynamically by controller variables.

I'd like to minify the js before appending/inline-ing it into the html file that it would be served out from.

I've tried `<render :partial => 'javascript.js'>` which is the standard way to render a partial in an erb.

Ideally i'd just be able to do  `<render :partial => Minify.new.minify('javascript.js')>` to render out a minified version of the js

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try the uglifier gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/uglifier), I don't know about the performance, but you can do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <%= raw Uglifier.new.compile(render "your_js_in_a_partial.js") %>
<script>
```

Comment: Hey Lucas, that works, just needs a raw for it `<%= raw Uglifier.new.compile(render "your_js_in_a_partial.js") %>`